# Windows PCL HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm reading a stream back from a server using System.Net.HttpClient.  The problem I have is that the stream is blocked until the entire response is in memory.  I'd like to start handling the response as data is coming from the network.  Waiting for the entire response before parsing, is too slow.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
...
await client.GetStreamAsync();
/* another way I tried */
HttpResponseMessage response = await clientGetAsync();
if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    await response.Content
}

await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Is there a way, it doesn't have to be with HttpClient, to get the stream as it is coming from the network using Windows Portable Class Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SendAsync` with the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to prevent `HttpClient` from buffering the response stream.  Once you have used this option, the `ReadAsStreamAsync` will return a wrapper around the actual network stream instead of a MemoryStream.